# How can i use # in dynamic column name?

Tags: sql, spring, oracle, mybatis, ibatis

In myBatis,

i want to use #{value} instead of ${value}

```
WITH TEMP (
    <if test="P_OGRP != null and P_OGRP.size() > 0">
        <foreach collection="P_PARAM" index="index" item="item">
        #{item.A}, #{item.B},
        </foreach>
    </if>)
SELECT * FROM TEMP

...
...
...
```

"#{value}" -> Is this not possible?

i shouldn't use service layer, only use sql

Thnaks.

Comment: Please see this [FAQ](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-difference-between--and-). Simply put, `select * from table1 where ${colName} = 1`  is OK, but `select * from table1 where #{colName} = 1` is not. `#{}` is a placeholder (i.e. `?`) in a `PreparedStatement` and you cannot use a placeholder for table/column name.